# CRUD query table issue

Tags: jsp, crud

I make a table and i'm going to update a row of data which include (location id , product id , product amount). I need both location_ID and product_ID to ensure that i update for the correct product_Amount. Then , when i click on the href which the following code shown (see link), it show message "The requested resource is not available." .

How to solve this, is this some kind of syntax error ? i need both the attributes (location_ID and product_ID ) to pass into the controller to perform update action.

[image: code]

Comment: can you please explain more, by putting your code. Its hard to understand what exactly you want

Comment: Provide, What you want to do, what is the issue, what you have tried, what is not working, What error it is showing

Comment: I make a table and i'm going to update a row of data which include (location id , product id , product amount). I need both location_ID and product_ID to ensure that i update for the correct product_Amount. Then , when i click on the href which the code above shown, it show message "The requested resource is not available." .

Comment: instead of link to code, post the code it self.

Comment: _"The requested resource is not available."_ It says page not found on the server, kindly check the url on the browser and the project directory if name of the file is correctly spelled.